# Why do I get response of an API request handled by an (exited) gunicorn worker?

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

Gunicorn config (only for testing):

```
workers = 1
max_requests = 2
timeout = 30
graceful timeout = 1
(all other unspecified/default)
```

**Log events:**

```
FIRST REQUEST:
[2023-07-25 16:01:29 +0000] [9485] [DEBUG] [pre_request] POST <API> - worker pid **9485**|ppid 29517|age 3|nr 0|max_requests 2|alive True|nr_pre 1|nr_post 0|sub_p_count 0
 
RESPONSE OF FIRST REQUEST:
[2023-07-25 16:01:44 +0000] [9485] [DEBUG] [post_request] POST <API> - worker pid **9485**|ppid 29517|age 3|nr 1|max_requests 2|alive True|nr_pre 1|nr_post 1|sub_p_count 0
 
SECOND REQUEST:
[2023-07-25 16:01:51 +0000] [9485] [DEBUG] [pre_request] POST <API> - worker pid **9485**|ppid 29517|age 3|nr 1|max_requests 2|alive True|nr_pre 2|nr_post 1|sub_p_count 0
 
WORKER EXIT:
[2023-07-25 16:01:51 +0000] [9485] [INFO] Autorestarting worker after current request.
(graceful timeout of 1s)
[2023-07-25 16:01:53 +0000] [9485] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: **9485**)
[2023-07-25 16:01:53 +0000] [9485] [DEBUG] Worker exited
 
RESPONSE OF SECOND REQUEST:
[2023-07-25 16:02:04 +0000] [9485] [DEBUG] [post_request] POST <API> - worker pid **9485**|ppid 29517|age 3|nr 2|max_requests 2|alive False|nr_pre 2|nr_post 2|sub_p_count 0
```

Unable to figure out if it is the expected behavior?